# One-to-Many in Django with multiple models as target

Tags: python, django, nosql

I'm making a patient database application. Each diagnosis would be filled in a form, which have many types of form. I'm doing this with Django with each form as a model.

However, seems that I cannot join the model to the Patient model. How should I join them?

Note that I'm not restricted to Django's ORM. I can move to CounchDB or other database that can scale to 10k patient records and over 100k diagnosis.

Comment: You know, the answer to "multiple models as target" is definitely generic foreign key, but I'm removing my answer to see what other more qualified people suggest for db design in this situation. Answered questions don't get any love.

Comment: like Yuji said, I'd recommend generic foreign key http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> scale to 10k patient records and over 100k diagnosis.

This is not a scale to be concerned about. Pretty much anything that can do this, can do this scale.

> I'm doing this with Django with each form as a model.

I don't see why that would be necessary. You should rather [create dynamic forms](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/nov/09/dynamic-forms/) ([another tutorial](http://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/)) that stores data back to the same model.

Other wise, you should resort to Generic Foreign Keys that are defined in the [content type framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/).